# Recreate Blender 3D's chromatic aberration in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, blender

I really like Blender 3D's Lens Distortion node. Specifically the chromatic aberration effect. I would like to recreate it in Photoshop but I can't figure it out.

Really like the pulling/stretching in the corners and the heavy chromatic aberration effect. I like how the center is still in focus but the distortion is amplified out into the corners.

After hours of trying I cannot figure it out. Does anyone here know how Blender is doing this exactly or can point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot get it by misusing Lens Correction. It is too smart, it doesn't generate chromatic aberration if there's none. But you can distort R,G and B channels differently.

Let's check the case with an example. It has big BW contrasts to get much color.

[image]

Duplicate the image layer to have a spare copy.

Insert to the duplicate a few percent radial zoom blur (Filter > Blur > Radial Blur > Zoom)

[image]

Open the Channels panel. Select the blurred layer in the Layers panel. Make a selection by applying Select All.

Select one channel, say R in the channels panel and stretch it symmetrically larger by holding  Shift+Alt at the same time. Select another channel, say B and stretch it smaller. The fake color aberration is ready:

[image]

The blur isn't a must, but it generates some intermediate colors which do not exist without blur. The daylight color spectrum which can be seen for example when one watches things through a thick magnifying glass is much richer than the 3 colors of RGB.

You can make the colors even richer by moving 2 channels apart in other way than radially (=by symmetric stretching). But that generates aberration to the whole image area. You can fool by inserting a radial gradient layer mask and let the original image cover the mid part:

[image]